# Upgrade versão do Ionic

Tags: ionic

Tenho projetos em Ionic 1.x, e vou iniciar um novo projeto, porém, gostaria de atualizar o Ionic para sua versão mais recente (estável).

Minha dúvida é sobre a compatibilidade, isto é, preciso saber se vou ter problemas ao criar "builds" com a versão anterior, pois o projeto que fiz anteriormente ainda precisará de manutenções e afins.

Até onde sei, ao atualizar o Ionic ele vai atualizar o Cordova, CLI e afins e estou com receio dessa mudança.

Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode atualizar sem medo. Eu tenho vários projetos com ionic 1 e comecei a algum tempo utilizar o Ionic 2.

O que defini as configurações do seu projeto são as informações do arquivo `package.json` do seu projeto. Lá esta a versão do ionic, cordova e plugins que vc está utilizando.

Após atualizar o Ionic você ainda poderá criar projetos com Ionic 1, basta rodar o script

> ionic start project_name blank --type ionic1

Boa sorte

Comment: Maravilha, André. Obrigado pela explicação.